# Why won't my function sit in a cell in my table?

Tags: php, html

My function(s) run fine and my table does fine with any other item I try to place in it, but any time I try to call a function to put in a cell, it tends to just place the echoed function above my table, rather than in a cell.

This is what ends up happening; rather than being placed under input, my lineLoop() function places above my table.

M Value: -2, X Value: 2, B Value: 0

M Value: -2, X Value: 5, B Value: 0

M Value: -2, X Value: 8, B Value: 0

M Value: -2, X Value: 10, B Value: 0

Formula     Input   Output

Y=MX+B

I have tried creating an array of functions to then place in the cell, I have also tried creating the cells using loops, but I am not experienced enough to figure it out (this is my first week of PHP).

```
<table>    
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Formula</th>
        <th>Input</th>
        <th>Output</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

<?php

$formula= array("Y=MX+B","A=4PiR^2","D=VT ");

echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $formula[0] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . lineLoop() . "</td>";


function lineLoop();
    $xvalue = array(2,5,8,10);
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
        echo "M Value: -2, X Value: " . $xvalue[$i] . ", B Value: 0" . "</br>";
    }
}
```

I expected my lineLoop() function to be placed in the next cell over instead of outside of the table.

Comment: You are currently having a syntax error at this line `function lineLoop();` from the code you post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll have to use “td” inside the forloop

```
echo "<td>M Value: -2, X Value: " . $xvalue[$i] . ", B Value: 0" . "</br></td>”
```